# How to VLOOKUP an array when there are empty fields in the date column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm trying to VLOOKUP the resolution date in another table.

```
Defect ID  State  Resolution Date
XYZ-1      Open   
XYZ-2      Closed 12 Mar 2015
```

When I see the looked up date for XYZ-1, it shows 1/1/1900 whereas for XYZ-2, it shows the actual date.

How do I get an empty value as is when I vlookup the first value ?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to wrap your VLOOKUP function inside an if.

Let's say that you are currently using the below VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:C,3,0)
```

You can wrap it inside an if, check if the vlookup returns 0, and replace that with an empty value:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:C,3,0)=0,"",VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:C,3,0))
```

For me it worked:

```
Defect ID | Vlookup here
-------------------------
XYZ-1     |
XYZ-2     | 12-Mar-15
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution offered by @tcsapunaru is what you are looking for but I will expand the error control a bit.

As mentioned, a `VLOOKUP()` or `INDEX(MATCH())` will return a zero if encountering a blank cell to return. A zero will show *1/1/1900* when formatted as a date. If you want to return a blank cell for either a blank return on the match *and* no match at all, wrap the first VLOOKUP in an `IFERROR` function so that you get a blank cell instead of an `#N/A` error.

```
=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet1!A:C, 3, FALSE), 0), VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet1!A:C, 3, FALSE), "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the same formula but just format the result cell to show a blank in the case where the `VLOOKUP` is returning a zero, e.g. just format result cell as:

`m/d/yyyy;;`

By adding the two semi-colons, zeroes and negative values are displayed as blanks. The underlying value will be zero but it will display as a blank rather than `1/0/1900` or similar